# ArrayList no suitable method

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to add everything from ArrayList in class Taster in another ArrayList in class Tastatura. It's calling no suitable method error and I don't really know what to do and how to do it . I would be really thankfull if someone quickly explained me how this work and write my code correctly.

This is main class:

```
public class Tastatura {     
public static void main(String[] args) {
Taster slovo = new Taster();

ArrayList<String> collection1 = new ArrayList<String>();
collection1.addAll(slovo);  //<--- error here
 }
 }
```

another class:

```
public class Taster {
    public Taster(){
     ArrayList<String> Slova = new ArrayList<String>();
         Slova.add("q");
         Slova.add("w"); }}
```

Comment: Well a `Taster` isn't a collection of strings - so it doesn't make sense to call `collection1.addAll(slovo)`... Do you at least understand the error?

Comment: Please don't make the mistake of having your class extend ArrayList.  This is not an inheritance situation.

Comment: @JonSkeet , yeah  , I'm a bit slow minded , I got it now . Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
collection1.addAll(slovo.Slova) ;
```

and change your Taster  class to this :

```
public class Taster {
    public ArrayList<String> Slova = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Taster(){
         Slova.add("q");
         Slova.add("w"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Now I noticed what I did wrong , this is working now . thank you. +1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is by `collection1.addAll(slovo);` you are adding an object to a collection.

The `addAll` method requires a `Collection` as argument.

You class should look like this :

```
public class Taster {
    private ArrayList<String> Slova;

    public Taster() {
        Slova = new ArrayList<String>();
         Slova.add("q");
         Slova.add("w"); 
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getList() {
        return Slova;
    }
 }
```

And in you `main` method :

`collection1.addAll(slovo.getList());`

**OR**

You don't need to change the `Taster` class :

Just change your `addAll` to :

`collection1.addAll(slovo.Slova);`

Comment: You and the OP should realize that private means nothing when you write code like this.  Anyone who calls that getList() method gets the private reference and can alter the state of that class as they wish.

Comment: @duffymo edited the answer, and added the simplest solution as "or".
Thanks :)

Comment: doesn't change anything.  That getList() method still renders your private modifier meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add class `Taster` into method, which expects String or something like that (`ArrayList<String>` in this case)

:)

Nafas code should work..

Other way is to write your own "add" method in your Taster class (which takes actual `ArrayList` and adds in it every item from `ArrayList` given in param, and returns that result)

Comment: Yeah , it worked , I noticed what I did wrong when he corrected it . Thank for your answer.